# object reference not set to an instance of an object error showing

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I run the following code it shows the error as "object reference not set to an instance of an object" :
(This codes change the value of DatagridViewComboBox as per other DatagridViewComboBox in same row and sharing same databse table.)

```
Private Sub dgv1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv1.CellValueChanged

    Try

        Dim currentrowindex As Integer = dgv1.CurrentRow.Index
        Dim obj As Object = dgv1.CurrentCell.Value           
        Me.dgv1(1, currentrowindex).Value = obj
        Me.dgv1(2, currentrowindex).Value = obj
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub dgv1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgv1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
   dgv1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
```

End Sub

Please tell me how can I fix this error ???

Comment: For the possible reasons of a NullReferenceException, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. That said, I suggest to run your application in Debug mode and check if any of your object references are `Nothing`. A candidate is `dgv1.CurrentRow`, another `dgv1.CurrentCell`.

Comment: Use a debugger to find the value which is Null. I suspect dgv1 is not initialized.

Comment: thanks I've done this:
Private Sub datagridview2_cellvaluechanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
        Try
            Dim currentrowindex As Integer = dgv2.CurrentRow.Index
            Dim obj As Object = dgv2.CurrentCell.Value   ' we can take STRING or OBJECT var is mandatory
            Me.dgv2(4, currentrowindex).Value = obj
            Me.dgv2(5, currentrowindex).Value = obj
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
handler in form load:
AddHandler dgv2.CellValueChanged,AddressOf datagridview2_cellvaluechanged

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone now I have done this as : 
Private Sub datagridview2_cellvaluechanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

```
    Try
        Dim currentrowindex As Integer = dgv2.CurrentRow.Index
        Dim obj As Object = dgv2.CurrentCell.Value   ' we can take STRING or OBJECT var is mandatory

        Me.dgv2(4, currentrowindex).Value = obj
        Me.dgv2(5, currentrowindex).Value = obj
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

End Sub

and add a handler in form load :
      AddHandler dgv2.CellValueChanged, AddressOf datagridview2_cellvaluechanged